# On what Stack Exchange site would questions about Google Data Studio go?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

Lately I've been learning Google [Data Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics#History) and I've had a lot of questions related to working with custom fields + Data Studio functions. When I google search problems or errors I'm getting, I'm used to seeing a bunch of Stack Overflow results, but with Data Studio being relatively new and undocumented, I haven't seen a single Stack Exchange site question.

If I do have a question, what site should I ask it on? My questions end up being a mix of Data Studio throwing an error, or how to accomplish X with Y.

Comment: Does your questions involve a specific programming problem that can have a specific answer?

Comment: Perhaps [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). A site's [Help Center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help) is always the first place to check. Specifically, [what to ask](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray, it seems like I'll need to split concept questions from debugging ones between DataScience and StackOverflow.

Comment: @SamuelLiew some questions are based on errors, those would involve specific answers VBA/Excel formula style.

Comment: Yes, programming questions can be asked on Stack Overflow, whether they arose from doing data science or anything else. But if they're not actually about programming (i.e., they are more conceptual style questions about data analytics), then they are probably a better fit on Data Science. Not being a data scientist myself or having much background in the field, I can't really provide you any more tailored advice than this, so I don't feel comfortable writing an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray you're good, I got the answer I was looking for. Wasn't sure if I was missing an exchange site that all DataStudio questions would fall perfectly into. It's a hybrid of simple coding and Data Analytics, so your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks.